# Combinatorics and Graph Theory

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways can a committee be formed from 4 men and 6 women with...
4 members, at least two whom are women and Mr and Mrs Baggins cannot be chosen

- I know I should do this problem from the converse point of view
- According to the answer key the answer is{[C(4,2)×C(6,2)]−(3×5)}+{[C(4,1)×C(6,3)]−C(5,2)}+C(6,4)
- Don't understand how to achieve this
- This question is driving me crazy !!!!

Any help is appreciated!!!!! #:D 
Thanks Joe!!!!!

Comment: WOW this question is stumping me too!

Comment: I do not understand where the 3*5 comes from

Answer (score 2):

You can have 2 men and 2 women, or 1 man and 3 women, or just 4 women. If we temporarily ignore the Baggins business, that $${4\choose2}{6\choose2}+{4\choose1}{6\choose3}+{6\choose4}$$

Now of the 2 men, 2 women ways, $3\times5$ use both Bagginses; of the 1 man, 3 women ways, ${5\choose2}$ ways use both Bagginses, and we're done.

Answer (score 2):

$2$ women committee - $\binom{6}{2}\cdot \binom{4}{2} - (3\cdot 5) = 75$

Explanation: Pick $2$ from $6$ women $(15)$ times $2$ from $4$ men $(6)$ minus the number of combinations which include Mr and Mrs Baggins $(15)$. Mrs Baggins can be paired with $5$ other women, and for every one of those, Mr Baggins can be paired with $3$ other men.

$3$ women committee - $\binom{6}{3}\cdot \binom{4}{1} - 10 = 70$

In this case, there are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ ways that Mrs Baggins can be grouped with $2$ other women and Mr Baggins.

$4$ women committee - $\binom{6}{4} = 15$

Total $= 160$

Comment: How do u know the number of combinations that include mr and mrs baggins is (15)

Comment: @Parley Mrs Baggins can be paired with 5 other women, and for every one of those, Mr Baggins can be paired with 3 other men.

Comment: Thank you, this was super helpful!!!!!!!!! To make it more explicit, the reasoning for the (3x5) is because (2C2)(5C1)(3C1) = 15 must be subtracted because this is a case in which both Mrs and Mr Baggins are selected, and the 10 comes from (2C2)(5C2)(3C0) because this is a case in which they are both selected as well. Thanks again @PhilH this is great!!!

Comment: The usual way to express appreciation for an answer here, 597223, is to "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that, 597223.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea behind this...

We need at least two women and mr and mrs Baggins cannot be included.

Case 1: 2 women
(4C2)(6C2) 
But Mr and Mrs Baggins can be in this arrangement so we need to subtract them out they appear in this arrangement 15 times so subtract that out

Case 2: 3 Women 
(4C1)(6C3)
Both Mr and Ms Baggins can be in this arrangement so we need to subtract them out they appear in this arrangement 10 times so subtract that out

Case 3: 4 Women 
(4C0)(6C4) Only Ms Baggins is included in this arrangement

So we are left with 75+70+15 which gives you 160 ways